# DRF AttributeError type object 'QuerySet' has no attribute 'nom'

Tags: python, django

I'm making my first DRF api I get a strange AttributeError that I don't understand. When I try to access to my data using a GET request, I get this error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `nom` on
>   serializer `ExpediteurSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `type` instance.
>   Original exception text was: type object 'QuerySet' has no attribute
>   'nom'.

I guess I've done something unexpected in my serializers.py file.. Here follows some snippets of my code.

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Expediteur(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tel = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from polls.serializers import ExpediteurSerializer, DestinataireSerializer, LettrePrioSerializer, TypeLettreRecoSerializer, LettreRecoSerializer, TimbrePrioSerializer, TimbreRecoSerializer
from polls.models import Expediteur, Destinataire, LettrePrio, TypeLettreReco, LettreReco, TimbrePrio, TimbreReco
from rest_framework import status, HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

import json
import datetime

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone

# Create your views here.

class ExpeViewSet(APIView):
    serializer_class = ExpediteurSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Expediteur.objects.all()
        serializer = ExpediteurSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from polls.models import Expediteur, Destinataire, LettrePrio, TypeLettreReco, LettreReco, TimbrePrio, TimbreReco


class ExpediteurSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    nom = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=50)
    prenom = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)
    adresse = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=200)
    tel = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Expediteur.objects.create(**validated_data)
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.nom = validated_data.get('nom', instance.nom)
        instance.prenom = validated_data.get('prenom', instance.prenom)
        instance.adresse = validated_data.get('adresse', insatnce.adresse)
        instance.tel = validated_data.get('tel', instance.tel)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the many flag in you view, like so:

```
ExpediteurSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

In general you could simplify your code very much by fully utilizing DRF.
First, make ExpediteurSerializer a ModelSerializer according to the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer).

Then you can also get rid of the create and update method, DRF takes care of all of that for you. And I strongly recommend you to look at ModelViewSets, they make your life very easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just changed to serializers.ModelSerializer and added class Meta: model = Expediteur but I keep having the same problem. I also removed my create and update method.

Comment: @Mehdi, please check my updated answer, but really switch to ModelViewSet and you can get rid of all that code.

Comment: thanks for your help, I've modified my code to have a proper serializer. I tried it with the shell and it works fine but now I have the this error: TypeError 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: You would need to make a new question for that with your new code.